# sql query null data was not retrieved

Tags: sql

[image]

Table DEPARTMEnT

[image: Table DEPARTMET]

TABLE EMPLOYEE

[image]

There is the Operations Department which has not any employee. So, i believed that the query would retrieved also the row(image 1):

Department_ID=10 , Department_Name =Operations, Employee=0

Why doesnt happen???

```
 SELECT EMPLOYEE.Department_ID, DEPARTMENT.Department_Name, Count(*) AS Employees 
FROM EMPLOYEE right JOIN DEPARTMENT ON DEPARTMENT.Department_ID = EMPLOYEE.Department_ID
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT.Department_Name,.EMPLOYEE.Department_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the principal data you care about for this query is coming from the DEPARTMENT table, you may want to consider rewriting your query to be:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.Department_ID, DEPARTMENT.Department_Name, Count(EMPLOYEE.Employee_ID) As Employees 
FROM DEPARTMENT 
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE ON EMPLOYEE.Department_ID = DEPARTMENT.Department_ID 
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT.Department_ID, DEPARTMENT.Department_Name
```

Comment: I tried it but the result was Department_ID=null , Department_Name =Operations, Employee=1(that cannot happen)

Comment: Right - that would be the result for this case.  I rewrote your query for what I believe you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The default `join` is an `inner join`, which only returns rows for which at least one row is found on both sides.  Replace `join` with `left join` to retrieve departments without employees.

Example code:

```
SELECT  e.Department_ID
,       d.Department_Name
,       count(e.Employee_ID) AS Employees 
FROM    Department d
LEFT JOIN
        Employee e
ON      d.Department_ID = e.Department_ID
GROUP BY 
        d.Department_ID
,       d.Department_Name
```

Comment: i replaced it but a get the same outputs

Comment: Uh, I see `department` is the right-hand table.  Try a `right join` instead of a `left join` ?

Comment: I tried it but the result was Department_ID=null , Department_Name =Operations, Employee=1(that cannot happen)

Comment: That's because you retrieve the department id from the employee record.  An easy fix would be to change `select employee.department_id, ...` to `select department.department_id, ...`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. You *could* put in a `RIGHT JOIN` if you have the `EMPLOYEE` table first, but the reason this is not good is because soon your queries will start being a mix of `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins, which becomes *very* hard to read, even for seasoned SQL professionals. By sticking with `LEFT JOIN` you keep the query maintainable and understandable. (In very rare circumstances `RIGHT JOIN` may simplify a query that has a complex order of precedence but I have only done it something like twice to avoid having to add parentheses around groups of joins).

```
SELECT
   D.Department_ID,
   D.Department_Name,
   Employees = Count(*) 
FROM
   dbo.DEPARTMENT D
   LEFT JOIN dbo.EMPLOYEE E
      ON D.Department_ID = E.Department_ID
GROUP BY
   D.Department_ID,
   D.Department_Name
```

Also, I recommend that you use aliases for your tables instead of full table names. The query becomes much easier to scan and understand when there is consistent use of aliases. Spelling out the entire table name all too often obscures other parts of the query.